# use a batch file to find full file names with partial matching then move them

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, find, dos, move

I need a batch file that will find all files in a folder with a set variable in there name and then move them to a different folder. This must work on a windows XP computer.

Example:

the folder has these files

```
abc123abc.pdf
efg123eft.pdf
hig456hig.pdf
```

if we search for file names that contain "123" then it would move both abc123abc.pdf and efg123eft.pdf to a set folder.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the names that have `123` anywhere in them:

```
move *123*.* c:\newfolder
```

If you want the `123` to always be the 4th, 5th, and 6th characters:

```
move ???123*.* c:\newfolder
```

If you want only `.pdf` files with `123` (either of the above matches):

```
move *123*.pdf c:\newfolder
```

Works either from a batch file or directly from the command prompt.

The `?` matches a single character, the `*` matches one or  more. These are called `wildcard operators` or simply `wildcards`.

To see how the wildcard operators work, open a command ("DOS") window in the folder you want to use, and try (`dir` is for a directory listing, and can't hurt anything to experiment with):

```
dir *.*

dir *123*

dir *123*.pdf

dir ???123*.pdf
```

Comment: The examples I gave you do exactly that - the wildcard gives you multiple (one or more) matches. See my last sentence, and see the `dir` command in the [command-line reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No need for a batch file - the move command with a wildcard will do that itself:

```
move *123* c:\where\ever
```